# Segmentation fault using char pointers in C

Tags: c, char

With my current implementation of code, I'm getting a segmentation fault that I think is caused by trying to store several char* in another char*. However, I don't know a way around this being fairly new to C. I'm in a GLUE Unix environment. The code compiles but does not fully execute.

Here's my method that I think is causing the issue.

```
int totalLogins = 0, selectedLogins = 0,dateIn[3], timeIn[3], dateOut[3], timeOut[3];
int latest = 0,earliest=30,loggedIn = 0, firstTime[7][3],firstDate[7][3],i;
char* user[12], firstUser[7][12];
bool first = true;


void checkAndSetEarliest(int day)
    {
        first = true;

        for(i = 0; i < 3 && first; i++)
        {
            first = (timeIn[i]<firstTime[day][i]);
        }

        if(first)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                firstTime[day][i] = timeIn[i];
                firstDate[day][i] = dateIn[i];
            }

            printf("user = %s\n",user);
            firstUser[day] = user;
        }
    }
```

timeIn[],firstTime[][],firstDate[][], and dateIn[] are all ints

firstUser[] and user[] are char*

I'm trying to edit the contents of firstUser with the value of user.

Comment: Is there anycode missing ? Where are declared within this scope firstTime & firstDate ?

Comment: Show the declarations of all the variables... otherwise this code is meaningless.

Comment: I added the declarations. I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

First, the way you are using `user[]` in `printf`, it is suppose to be a char array, not an array of pointer to char (what you have declared).

Secondly, `firstuser` is a 2d arrray and you are using it as a 1d array.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to show the definition of the variables this function uses. Fair chance that last line should be changed to:

```
strcpy( FirstUser[day], user );
```

Comment: `firstUser` is of type `char*` or `char[]`, so `firstUser[day]` is a single `char`.  OP really needs to show variable declarations.